# How do you create a non-Thread-based Guice custom Scope?

Tags: scope, guice

It seems that all Guice's out-of-the-box Scope implementations are inherently Thread-based (or ignore Threads entirely):

`Scopes.SINGLETON` and `Scopes.NO_SCOPE` ignore Threads and are the edge cases: global scope and no scope.

`ServletScopes.REQUEST` and `ServletScopes.SESSION` ultimately depend on retrieving scoped objects from a `ThreadLocal<Context>`.  The retrieved `Context` holds a reference to the `HttpServletRequest` that holds a reference to the scoped objects stored as named attributes (where name is derived from `com.google.inject.Key`).

Class `SimpleScope` from the custom scope Guice wiki also provides a per-Thread implementation using a `ThreadLocal<Map<Key<?>, Object>>` member variable.

With that preamble, my question is this: how does one go about creating a non-Thread-based Scope?  It seems that something that I can use to look up a `Map<Key<?>, Object>` is missing, as the only things passed in to `Scope.scope()` are a `Key<T>` and a `Provider<T>`.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: It might help if you explain how you want the Scope to decide if it should create a new object or reuse an existing one. Another way to look at it is what you want the the lifetime of the objects to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you want - you don't want scopes that are based on threads, and you don't want scopes that ignore threads.

But yes, scopes are intended to manage the lifecycle of an object and say when an instance should be reused. So really you're asking "what are the other possibilities for re-using an instance beyond 'always use the same instance', 'never use the same instance', and 'use an instance depending on the execution environment of the current thread'?"

Here's what comes to mind:

- Use the same instance for a fixed amount of time. The example here would be of a configuration file that's reloaded and reparsed every ten minutes.
- Perform some network call to query whether a given object should be re-used (maybe it's a fast call to determine whether we need to reconstruct the object, but the call for reconstructing the object is slow)
- Re-use the same object until some outside call comes in telling us to reload
- Re-use the same object per thread, but not with a scope that's explicitly entered and left like the servlet scopes. (So one instance per thread)
- A "this thread and child threads" scope that is based on an `InheritableThreadLocal`, not a plain `ThreadLocal`.
- Related to that, a `Scope` and a threadpool-based `ExecutorService` that work togehter so that instances are shared between a thread and jobs it submits for background execution.
- Pull instances out of a pool; this is tricky, since we'd need a good way to return objects to the pool when finished. (Maybe you could combine this idea with something like the request scope, so that objects can be returned to the pool when the request ends)
- A scope that composes two or more other scopes, so for example we could get a configuration object that is re-read every 10 minutes except that the same instance is used through the lifetime of a given request.

Comment: This is all good food for thought.  In the end, I decided that I didn't really need a Scope at all; I just needed to properly declare binding annotations, use private modules, and expose only those bindings that I wanted.